# SWIFT: Error Encountered When Creating a Struct Method which Returns a Random Item In An Array Using A Class

Tags: arrays, swift, class, methods

I've created a struct in Swift containing a list of full names generated by a class:

```
class nameDetails {

    var fullName: String

    init(fullName: String) {
        self.fullName = fullName
    }

}

struct nameList {

    let theList = [
        nameDetails(fullName: "Bob Smith"),
        nameDetails(fullName: "John Doe"),
        nameDetails(fullName: "Sarah Taylor"),
        nameDetails(fullName: "Gene Black"),
        nameDetails(fullName: "Harry Snoden"),
        nameDetails(fullName: "Lucy Lu"),
        nameDetails(fullName: "Greg Smith")
    ]

    func getRandomName() {
        var sizeOfList = theList.count
        var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(sizeOfList)))

        return theList[randomNumber]
    }

}
```

I'm trying to use the method to return a random item in the list. But the 'return' statement is stating the following error: 
'nameDetails' is not convertible to '()'

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the return type of `func getRandomeName()`

It should be `func getRandomName()->nameList`